# How to send a message in an Electron renderer window from one JavaScript class/file to another?

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc, communication

​I am creating an electron app and all my parts are broken out into separate classes (separate files).  I would like to be able to have one class talk to another using something similar to ipcRender.send and ipcMain.on however I want to communicate between two pieces of code inside the Electron renderer.  How do I do that?

I could do something silly like mainWindow.webContents.send, receive the message in the main window using ipcRenderer.on, and then immediately send that same message back using ipcRenderer.send to then receive it via ipcMain.on but that seem a little crazy.

Is there a way to send data around in the Electron App, without having to go through Main?

Comment: Do you communicate between (child-)windows or is it just calling a function from another file or something else? Could you add an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can use ipcRenderer.emit in one class, and in another class I can hear the messages using ipcRenderer.on

Answer (score 0):

I think what would work for you would be to call functions defined in other files.

An example would be like in file 1 you would have this:

```
exports.myFunction = function (arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1);
    console.log(arg2);
};
```

And in file 2 you would have this:

```
var file1 = require('./file1.js');

file1.myFunction('arg1', 'arg2');
```

So if you were to run file 2 then it would call a function in file 1 that would console.log `arg1` and `arg2`.

You can also do the same thing with variables like this:

File 1:

```
exports.customVar = 'placeholder';
```

File 2:

```
var file1 = require('./file1.js');

console.log(file1.customVar);
```

If you were to run file 2 it would console.log `placeholder`